# Responsive css same width different height

Tags: css, responsive-design

Lets say i want to make my div responsive for same width but different height. 
Same width but if height is different, it will optimize the div different, like the code below but it is not working.

```
@media all and(min-width:1280px) and (height:768px){ 
  #myDiv{height:84%}
}
@media all and(min-width:1280px) and (height:1200px){ 
   #myDiv{height:97%}
}
```

Comment: Demo it or it didn't happen. :)

Comment: Just try giving a space between 'and' and '('. 
Just a guess.

Comment: why would you use `(height:768px)` and not `max-height` or `min-height`.

If you use `height`, then your `viewport` need to have the exact height as in your `CSS`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) and (max-height: 768px){
#myDiv{height:84%}
} 

@media all and(min-width:1280px) and (max-height:1200px) and (min-height: 769px){ 
   #myDiv{height:97%}
}
```